# Expo EAS build failed : Failed to upload the project tarball to EAS Build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

So, just like a normal day i wanna make an expo app, but this time it give me an error when i run "npx eas-cli build --profile development"

```
Compressing project files and uploading to EAS Build. Learn more: https://expo.fyi/eas-build-archive
× Compressing project files
Failed to upload the project tarball to EAS Build

Reason: Cannot copy 'C:\Users\F' to a subdirectory of itself, 'C:\Users\F\AppData\Local\Temp\eas-cli-nodejs\579c2de5-b407-437c-8a83-3af512494f85-shallow-clone'.
    Error: build command failed
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found for this issue is to use GitHub Actions to build your app. Here's how you can set it up:

#### How to Create a `.yml` File for GitHub Actions:

1. In your GitHub repository, navigate to the **Actions** tab.
2. Click on the **"New workflow"** button.
3. You can either choose a template or set up a workflow yourself. To set up a custom workflow, click on the **"Set up a workflow yourself"** option.
4. This will open an editor where you can define your workflow. You can name the file something like `build.yml`.
5. Copy and paste the following YAML configuration into the editor:

```yaml
name: EAS Build

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Install and build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
          cache: npm
      - name: Setup Expo and EAS
        uses: expo/expo-github-action@v8
        with:
          eas-version: latest
          token: ${{ secrets.EXPO_TOKEN }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Install expo CLI
        run: npm install -g expo-cli
      - name: Publish on expo server
        run: eas build --profile preview --platform ios
      - name: Update on Expo
        run: eas update --auto



Don't forget to obtain your Expo token. You can refer to the Expo documentation on Programmatic Access to learn how to get your personal access token. https://docs.expo.dev/accounts/programmatic-access/#personal-access-tokens
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine simply using git init, you can check here for detailed explanation.

just run the git init command on your project since EAS needs it to upload the files

https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/eas-build-archive.md

Answer (score 0):

To solve this challenge of this error when running expo Compressing project files
Failed to upload the project tarball to EAS Build
Reason: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir ElevatedDiagnostics
This error is as a result of you not running the code in administrator mode'

Step one : open your command line using administrator
step two : Cd into your directory of your expo project
finally step three: run the code again> eas build --profile development --platform android

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).